# How to download image from google sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have image in cell in google sheet and I want to download it using python. It would be best if it could be done using API. I searched the internet, but I haven't found solution.

I have [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-p3zN9B6ICuSCy6TALX4efLRVSIw0hNvzPdbI6Bbfk/edit?usp=sharing) and I want to download image in cell A1. It cant be even accessed in sheets. The only thing I can do now is copy the cell to word and it copies the image.

Answer (score 1):

Google's sheets API doesn't currently support the download of image files directly through python, sorry.

Comment: And is there any other way how to store images on google  sheets, so they could be downloaded with python?

Comment: Not that I know of, you could use google collab which has a direct API for python